# Power Apps list form not displaying Append changes Multi line Text values

Tags: powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint Online Column: Multiple lines of text with rich text with append options on.

I can view the values of multi line text by clicking "View entries" in the list view
[image]

[image]

However the same is not showing previous text when Viewing the From in PowerApps form.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Strange, I can't recall this being an issue with classic SharePoint lists. I've now turned off the "Append changes to existing text" option on the multiline field and it now works as expected in PowerApps. This did wipe out all existing data in that column so keep that in mind if you think of doing that.

Comment: Thank you. Having turned off "Append Changes" is not the issue. I need values after turning on "Append Changes" so I can capture previous values.